# How to optimize Bitbucket pipeline for Sonarcloud scan pipe?

Tags: bitbucket, sonarqube-scan, bitbucket-pipelines, sonarcloud

Every time Sonarcloud scanner starts, it download the image. It slowing down whole pipeline and generate additional cost.

Poor documentation don't have any information about additional cache https://bitbucket.org/sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan/src/master/

```
1.1.0: Pulling from sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan
27833a3ba0a5: Pulling fs layer
16d944e3d00d: Pulling fs layer
6aaf465b8930: Pulling fs layer
0684138f4cb6: Pulling fs layer
...
646f14b7521f: Pull complete
94dd58113625: Pull complete
41b91f2908b5: Pull complete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use cache for docker (Docker is used internally in sonarcloud-scan pipe).

After enabling cache it runs **faster by 1 minute**

```yaml
    - step: &sca
          image: atlassian/default-image:2  #quickest image
          name: SonarCube SCA
          caches:
            - docker
          script:
            - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.1.0
            - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-quality-gate:0.1.3
          services:
            - docker
```

More info: https://gist.github.com/GetoXs/e2b323b048aad88c12a10aceba3cc6cd